# I want to disable printing and saving of a webpage from file menu with JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, printing, save

Please help I want a code for disabling printing and saving of a webpage from file menu with JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a CSS style that will only be visible when printing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Then I guess you can do something like:

```
*{
    color:#fff !important;
    background:#fff !important;
    line-height:0 !important;
    font-size:0 !important;
    height:0 !important;
    width:0 !important;
    /*...*/
}
```

Here is also a [tutorial](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml).

This won't prevent printing, but should work for what you want.

About preventing the page to be saved, that is impossible, if they are viewing the page, they already downloaded it actually. The best you can is to obfuscate your code to make it unreadable.

Obfuscating/Compressor Tools:

- [HTML](http://vzone.virgin.net/phil.ronan/obfuscate.html)
- [CSS](http://www.csscompressor.com/)
- [JavaScript](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to disable printing with some clever CSS but I do not believe you are going to be able to prevent a user from saving the page. A web page can't really modify the behavior of the browser to that extent.

To clarify, when I say disable printing, you may be able to cause it to only print a blank page, not truly disable it.